# Creating keyspace with replication factor 1 on a 4 node cluster

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I just started learning cassandra and I have a dumb question;

Say for example I have a cassandra cluster of 4 nodes and I create a keyspace myKeySpace using SimpleStrategy and ReplicationFactor 1. Since I have chosen RF as 1, I mean to say that my data for this keyspace to be replicated to 1 node in the cluster.

But when I created table and inserted a row in this keyspace/table, I saw this new row is getting inserted in to all nodes in my cluster (select * on all nodes showed this row).

My question is since I have chosen RF as 1 for this keyspace, I would have expected one node in this cluster should have owned this data, not the rest of the nodes.

PLease clarify and correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication factor 1 does not mean that a single node holds all your data, it means that *the cluster* only holds a single copy of your data.

It basically means that every node in your cluster holds 25% of your data, and if *any* node is lost, your data won't be fully available.

You can also calculate how your cluster behaves using the [cassandra calculator](http://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/).

Comment: say for example i tried to insert a data like insert into mytable (id, name) values (1, 'user'), and id is my primary key, then the partitioner should have written this data to only one node in the cluster (ideally the first node in the ring - say i have single token nodes in my cluster).